# How to use "find" to prune some directories while keep some subdirectories

Tags: shell, find

There's an example:

```
#tree
.
├── dir1
│   ├── file1
│   ├── subdir1
│   │   └── file11
│   ├── subdir2
│   │   └── file12
│   ├── subdir3
│   ├── subdir4
│   ├── subdir5
│   └── subdir6
├── dir2
├── dir3
│   └── dir1
│       └── file11
├── dir4
├── dir5
└── dir6
```

The following command find all files except those under `dir1` and `dir2`.

```
find -not \( -path './dir1' -prune -o -path './dir2' -prune \)
```

My question is how to find all files except `dir1`, `dir2` while still search into subdirectory: `./dir/subdir1` ?

I tried some like this, but doesn't work. I don't know what's the right way to combine logical expressions.

```
find -not \( \
  \( -path './dir1' -a -not -path './dir1/subdir1' \) -prune -o \
  -path './dir2' -prune \)
```

---

Forgot to mention that I just wanna know how to use the logical combination in command `find`: `-o` `-a` `-not`, etc to achieve this. Using filters (`grep`,`sed`,`awk`) after the output of `find` works, but beyonds my question. Thanks to everyone has posted their answer.

---

Excepted Output:

```
.
./dir6
./dir5
./dir4
./dir3
./dir3/dir1
./dir3/dir1/file11
./dir1/subdir1
./dir1/subdir1/file11
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try:

```
find . \( -not -path './dir1/*' -and -not -path './dir2/*' -or -path './dir1/subdir1/*' \) -type f
```

Edit:

Considering prune, I think you should use:

```
find . \( -path './dir1/*' -and -not -path './dir1/subdir1*' -or -path './dir2' \) -prune -or -type f -print
```

Comment: Just find a way to keep prune in command, which should be faster since it wouldn't descend into `dir2`. Try: `find ./ -not \( \( -path './dir1*' -and -not -path './dir1/subdir1*' \) -o -path './dir2' -prune \)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find . -type f |sed '/.\/dir[12]\/[^/]*$/d'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>tree
.
├── dir1
│   ├── file1
│   ├── subdir1
│   │   └── file11
│   ├── subdir2
│   │   └── file12
│   ├── subdir3
│   ├── subdir4
│   ├── subdir5
│   └── subdir6
├── dir2
├── dir3
│   └── dir1
│       └── file11
├── dir4
├── dir5
└── dir6

13 directories, 4 files

>find | awk '
  {
    if($1 !~ /^\.\/dir1$/ && $1 !~ /^\.\/dir2$/) {
      if ($1 ~ /^\.\/dir1\//) {
        if ($1 ~ /^\.\/dir1\/subdir1(\/|$)/) {
          print($1)
        }
      } else if ($1 !~ /\.\/dir2\//) {
        print($1)
      }
    } 
  } '
.
./dir6
./dir5
./dir4
./dir3
./dir3/dir1
./dir3/dir1/file11
./dir1/subdir1
./dir1/subdir1/file11
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But `./dir1/subdir[2345]` should be excluded.

Comment: @LaputaPrince I update my answer use awk . Have a try:).

Comment: Yes,Bro. See @liberize 's answer and my comment above. awk is awesome but beyonds my question. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

man find

```
-mindepth levels
              Do not apply any tests or actions at levels less than levels (a  non-negative  integer).-min-depth 1 means process all files except the command line arguments.
```

this is not test!

```
find dir1 -mindepth N -type f
```